# How can I resolve DNS issues with Elastic Beanstalk, Nginx?

Tags: nginx, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get a super simple Flask server up and running with Docker on Elastic Beanstalk. When I navigate to the domain associated with the EB environment, all I see is a big fat 502 Bad Gateway Error.

Digging a bit deeper, I'm seeing the below error in the Nginx logs in EB:

```
2021/12/26 01:00:24 [error] 16944#16944: *682 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.23.137, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:5000/", host: "172.31.1.207"
```

In `eb-stdouterr.log`, it reports that the server is up and running:

```
web_1  |  * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
web_1  |  * Environment: production
web_1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
web_1  |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
web_1  |  * Debug mode: on
web_1  |  * Running on all addresses.
web_1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
web_1  |  * Running on http://172.24.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I found the public IP address associated with the EC2 instance, and I was actually able to query that using `curl` with the expected results, so it feels like this is a DNS issue. Any tips or suggestions? I've really no clue how to debug further.

Configuration:

- AWS Linux 2
- Docker Python image 3.9-buster
- Flask server

**Edit: From this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-env-cfg.healthd-logging), it looks like using docker-compose means you shouldn't be using Nginx?** I went and disabled it, but I still have the 502 Bad Gateway issue and no relevant error logs.

Here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.9-buster
COPY . /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD python app.py
```

And here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

Please help, thanks in advance :D

Comment: Found this interesting note on some AWS documentation
"Elastic Beanstalk assumes that you run a web server proxy as a container."
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-env-cfg.healthd-logging

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by removing my docker-compose.yml file altogether. I think there's some amount of configuration that has to be done to either resolve proxy configuration or (maybe?) use a custom docker image. Not sure which of the issues it was, but just using the Dockerfile in my root directory is working.